# Protractor: locating/clicking a button on the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, protractor

I am trying to figure out how to identify and click the button listed at the bottom.

```
<div class="media-body feed-item">

<div class="media-main" ng-class="{'no-avatar' : feed.type === 'Newsfeed' || feed.type === 'ProductItem' || feed.type === 'PollResult' || feed.type === 'GoalKeyResultUpdate'}">

<div class="meta meta-actions mar-bot10 has-icon" ng-class="{'has-icon': feed.type !== 'Newsfeed' &amp;&amp; feed.type !== 'ProductItem' &amp;&amp; feed.type !== 'PollResult'}">

<ul class="inline clearfix">

<li ng-if="!feed.MeCongrated &amp;&amp; userData.memberActive" class="ng-scope">
<button type="button" class="btn-meta ng-scope" ng-click="congrats(feed)" translate="profile.partials.rec.fee.lik"> Like</button></li>
```

Comment: What have you tried? See [Ask] in the Help Center.

Comment: `$('li button.btn-meta.ng-scope[ng-click="congrats(feed)"]').click();`. But that&amp;#39;s really that basic as if you&amp;#39;d ask &amp;quot;what is protractor&amp;quot;.
Please do some research or tutorials on [protractortest.org](http://protractortest.org). Also youtube offers a lot of examples, if you look for.

Comment: use `element(by.partialButtonText("Like")).click()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 element(by.ButtonText("Like")).click()
```

or

```
element(by.partialButtonText("Like")).click()
```

If the class is unique:

```
element(by.className("btn-meta ng-scope")).click()
```

By css:

```
element(by.css("btn-meta.ng-scope")).click()
```

Another way for selecting by css:

```
element(by.css("[ng-click='congrats(feed)']")).click()
```

Select by xpath:

```
element(by.xpath(".//button[@ng-click='congrats(feed)']")).click()
```

Or you can create custom selector by ng-click.